# SKReceiptRefreshRequest in StoreKit 2

Tags: swift, swiftui, storekit

Hie, so I'm adding IAPs to our SwifUI App and I use receipt validation before allocating products to users. The Receipt validation is done by using my Server (Node.js REST API), which validates them (receipts) on https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt.

Before sending the receipt to the server, I fetch the latest receipts from the device and then send them to the server for validation. I'm using StoreKit 2 in the app for this entire process, but here is my issue:

- After making a purchase, I can't find receipts on my device so I have to lean to the StoreKit 1 function called ***SKReceiptRefreshRequest*** to refresh receipts then I can send the latest receipts for validation.

The above works, but it's a messy implementation that I'd like assistance with. Here's my code:

```
class IAPManager: NSObject, SKRequestDelegate
{
    @Published var toBeBool = true;
    func refreshReceipt() -> Bool{
        let request = SKReceiptRefreshRequest(receiptProperties: nil)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
        return toBeBool
    }
    
    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest){
            if request is SKReceiptRefreshRequest {
                toBeBool = true
            }
        }
        
    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error){
        if request is SKReceiptRefreshRequest {
            print("In the SKReceiptRefreshRequest")
            toBeBool = false
        }
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

class Store: ObservableObject {

    let iAPManager = IAPManager() //I have to call my IAPManager like this in order to make it work
    
    /*
        After calling my purchase function, I need to send a payload that contains my receipt and originalTransactionID to my server for validation e.g
        
        {
            receiptData: "gGHUu9989h7847894............",
            originalTransactionID: "20000000000000"
        }
    */
    
    func creditPayment(_ json: Transaction) async {
        
        let refresh = iAPManager.refreshReceipt() //MY PROBLEM LIES HERE
       
        if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
            FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {

            do {
                
                let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
                let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
                  
                let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                let payload = ["receiptData": receiptString, "originalTransactionId": String(json.originalID)]
                
           
                guard let url = URL(string: "")
                    return
                }
                
                guard var request = NetworkManager.authenticatedRequest(url) else {
                    // stop loading screen/processing
                    
                    print("(debugging) :: calling failed make request  (101)")
                    successfulPurchase = false
                    return
                }
                
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                do {
                    
                    let jsonData = try encoder.encode(payload)
                    request.httpBody = jsonData
                } catch {
                    print("(debugging) :: jsonData -> ", String(describing: error))
                    successfulPurchase = false
                    // stop loading screen/processing
                    return
                }
                
                //SEND FOR VALIDATION
            }
            catch {
                print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription)
                successfulPurchase = false
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("No receipt found")
        }
    }


}
```

1. How can I take the code in `IAPManager` and place it in the `Store` function?
2. Sometimes the Receipt refresh brings up old receipts then I need to delete the entire app and use a new Sandbox account in order to get proper receipts?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_at_all_stages_of_development_with_xcode_and_sandbox

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting-up-storekit-testing-in-xcode

Comment: Hie @loremipsum, thanks for your response, unfortunately, the links you've attached don't cover the above scenario. I wish Apple had better documentation for Receipt refreshing in SK2

Comment: You should be using a StoreKit configuration file and StoreKit 2 has [sync()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/appstore/3791906-sync), `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` is not needed

Comment: Hie @loremipsum, the StoreKit configuration file is for local testing, this means you can't verify the receipts with the App Store Server API. In my scenario, I'm doing sandbox testing therefore I don't use a StoreKit configuration file, I must fetch my products from App Store Connect. I'll have look at the sync function, but I believe I have it in place. However, you need the device to pull the latest receipt which requires refreshing.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem @AshleyDube? I'm looking at the same issues unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @Knolraap, I unfortunately didn't get far enough. The product owner was not keen on Apple taking 30% of the revenue so they pulled the plug a few days after I posted my question